# Верстка таблиц под мобильные версии

Tags: html, css

На сайте много динамических таблиц, стал вопрос адаптации мод мобильные версии, все делал на основе `bootstrap` и все нормально отображает в мобильной версии кроме таблиц. Нашел такое решения

`<div class="table-responsive" style="max-width: 100%; overflow: auto;"></div>`
Появляется прокрутка и все ок, подскажите есть еще решения ?

Comment: так это же вроде стандартное решение от bootstrap., чем оно вас не устраивает?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев все  устраивает, хотел узнать может есть еще варианты решения ?

Comment: Вот совет [как перестроить таблицу под мобильник](http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20160829/). Но это уже не просто вёрстка, а изменение подачи данных.

Comment: Есть, посмотрите в статье на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/328230/